# 100% width with background repeat

Tags: html, css

I have plans to create carousel with a background that spans the width of the browser.
To do this I set `margin:0; padding:0;` in the body and set my `div` that spans the background to `width:100%`. I chose this because it contains another `div` that has a left, and right margin:auto; making the second `div` centred within the `div` spanning the browser.

I encountered a problem trying to add the background image to the `div` that spans the width of the browser. When I use `background-repeat:repeat-x;` it is still just a 550x1 px sliver on the far left of the browser. It does not repeat. I have figured this is due to the 100% width. If I let go of the 100% width I encounter a problem of the inner `div` being forced to the right or left, depending on the resolution of the monitor being used. I do not want this to happen.

Does anyone know of a way I can achieve/simulate 100% width and still use `background-repeat:repeat-x;`?

EDIT, i use 2 divs because i am applying silverlight, and would like to place it kindof artistically on the screen. here is my code, it might make more sence what i am doing then. and if you still believe 1 div is better than 2, tell me that im wrong, but here is the code. it is very simple because much will be done in silverlight, or at least i thought it would be somewhat simple, but that's how it goes.

```
HTML
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="imd_data_Home" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id=NavContainer>
<div id="Navigation">
    <img src="img_data/dem_Logo.png" id="Logo"/>
</div>

</div>
<div id="Carousel">
<div id="SilverlightContainer">

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>








CSS
body 
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#000061;
}

#NavContainer
{
    width:900px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#Navigation
{
    height:75px;
    width:100%;
}

#Logo
{
    float:left;
}

#Carousel
{
    height:550px;
    width:100%;
    background-image:url('img_data/carousel_bar_01.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

#SilverlightContainer
{
    height:550px;
    width:900px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: This is a bit tough to imagine. It's quite better if you post your code here

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to read, and could use some sample code with what you got so far in code blocks. If you edit the question there will be a header above the input area with some help icons as well (plus: you can live preview changes to your answer below the input box).

Comment: please post your code here....

Comment: ye, as mentioned earlier need code here. anyway try to use display property on css.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to take two div's to achieve what you want.
Just take your background image in the body like

```
body{ background:url(image path here) repeat-x}
```

and give your div
certain width and give it a style like

```
div#yourID{margin:auto}
```

This will work for you just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
body {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background:url(your-image.jpg) repeat-x;
 position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need only one div, the one you want in the middle.

```
<div class="centered"></div>
```

You set the background on the body:

```
body {
    min-height: 550px; 
    background: url(path/image.png) repeat-x;
    background-size: 1px 550px;
}
```

And then you have the centered div:

```
.centered {
    min-height: 150px; /* whatever values you wish for height and width */
    width: 300px;
    margin: 75px auto; /* whatever values you wish for top/ bottom margin */
}
```

You can see it live at http://dabblet.com/gist/2774626

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The problem was that I was not putting in the right location for the image `carousel_bar_01.png`.